# Aligning Table in Minipage

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, minipage

I would like to align this table with a second one (horizontally), however using minipage will lead to them being displayed below each other.
What did I set wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{arydshln}% draw dash-lines in tables
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}
\usepackage{diagbox}% diagonal box
\usepackage{multirow}% multirow for diagonal box

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Territoriale Kategorien}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{l} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Territiorien}}  \\ 
\midrule
China                                      \\
Russland                                   \\
Deutschland                                \\
England                                    \\
Europa                                     \\
Frankreich                                 \\
Mandschurei                                \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\label{ta:territory}
\\Quelle: XYZ\\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{l} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Territiorien}}  \\ 
\midrule
China                                      \\
Russland                                   \\
Deutschland                                \\
England                                    \\
Europa                                     \\
Frankreich                                 \\
Mandschurei                                \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\label{ta:territory2}
\\Quelle: XYZ\\
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add a `%` right after the first `\end{minipage}` to get both minipages to show up side by side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the expected output and captions, here are three possibilities:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{arydshln}% draw dash-lines in tables
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}
\usepackage{diagbox}% diagonal box
\usepackage{multirow}% multirow for diagonal box


\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\caption{Territoriale Kategorien - with minipages, individual caption for each table}
\label{ta:territory-minipage-first}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Territiorien}}  \\ 
\midrule
China                                      \\
Russland                                   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\smallskip

Quelle: XYZ
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\caption{Territoriale Kategorien - with minipages, individual caption for each table}
\label{ta:territory-minipages-second}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Territiorien}}  \\ 
\midrule
China                                      \\
Russland                                   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\smallskip

Quelle: XYZ
\end{minipage}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\caption{Territoriale Kategorien - without minipages, shared caption for both tables}
\label{ta:territory-tabular-both}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{l} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Territiorien}}  \\ 
\midrule
China                                      \\
Russland                                   \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Quelle: XYZ}
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}[t]{l} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Territiorien}}  \\ 
\midrule
China                                      \\
Russland                                   \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Quelle: XYZ}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Territoriale Kategorien - with subtables, shared caption for both tables and individual subcaption for each table}\label{ta:territory-subcaption-both}
\begin{subtable}{0.45\linewidth}
\caption{subcaption}\label{ta:territory-subcaption-first}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Territiorien}}  \\ 
\midrule
China                                      \\
Russland                                   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\smallskip

Quelle: XYZ
\end{subtable}
\hfill
\begin{subtable}{0.45\linewidth}
\caption{subcaption}\label{ta:territory-subcaption-second}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Territiorien}}  \\ 
\midrule
China                                      \\
Russland                                   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\smallskip
Quelle: XYZ
\end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```