# my \begin won't work

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, hline

when I try to use a `\begin{left}` and `\begin{right}`, they get mixed up. this is my code

```
\begin{left}
    \begin{tabular}{l|c|c}
        Monophthongs & Front & Back \\
        \hline
        Close & i iː & u uː \\
        Mid & e eː & o oː \\
        Open & a aː
    \end{tabular}
\end{left}
\begin{right}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
         Diphthongs & a & e & i & o & u \\
         \hline
         a &  & ae &  &  & au \\
         e &  &  & ei &  & eu \\
         u &  &  & ui &  &  \\
         i &  &  &  & io & iu \\
         o &  & oe &  &  &  \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{right}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What exactly do you want to achieve by using `\begin{left}... \end{left}` and `\begin{right}...\end{right}` here? Do you want both tables to show up side by side?

Comment: If you're interested in two side by side tables, you may want to givethe following a try: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{l|c|c}
Monophthongs & Front & Back \\
\hline
Close & i iː & u uː \\
Mid & e eː & o oː \\
Open & a aː
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{c|ccccc}
Diphthongs & a & e & i & o & u \\
\hline
a &  & ae &  &  & au \\
e &  &  & ei &  & eu \\
u &  &  & ui &  &  \\
i &  &  &  & io & iu \\
o &  & oe &  &  &  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}` The corresponding output looks like the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlR4I.png

Comment: Thanks! Im going to see if this works!

Comment: @leandriis +1. I would have done the same thing

Comment: @leandriis Probably the OP is looking for `\begin{tabular}[t]{c|c|c|c|c|c}` on the right side

Comment: I'm looking for two side to side tables, one with the monothongs and one with the dipthongs.

Answer (score 6):

I guess, you wanted to get both tables to show up side by side. To achieve this, remove the `left` and `right` environment and make sure, there is no empty line between the first `\end{tabular}` and the following `\begin{tablar}`. To get a small horizontal white space between both tables, I used `\quad` here, but you could also usa any other [command for horizontal spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/134144) of your choice here.

To make sure, both tables are top aligned with respect to each other, I added `[t]` to both `tabular` environments. Other options include `[c]` for vertically centered and `[b]` for  bottom alignment.

Lastly, I also added the missing column specifiers in your second table. Using `c|c` you only declared 2 columns, but used a total of 6 columns in your table. I thus changes that to `c|ccccc`. Feel free to change the column specifiers to suit your needs.

If you want to add a caption for both tables of an individual caption for each table, take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597566/134144 for an overview over different options and approaches on how to do that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}[t]{l|c|c}
        Monophthongs & Front & Back \\
        \hline
        Close & i iː & u uː \\
        Mid   & e eː & o oː \\
        Open  & a aː
    \end{tabular}
\quad
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c|ccccc}
         Diphthongs & a & e & i & o & u \\
         \hline
         a &  & ae &    &    & au \\
         e &  &    & ei &    & eu \\
         u &  &    & ui &    &    \\
         i &  &    &    & io & iu \\
         o &  & oe &    &    &    \\
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted, and it worked great!