# How to add caption under graph

Tags: graphics, captions, graphs, overleaf

how can I add captions underneath two graphs (one for each graph)? Here it is the code

```
\begin{center}
\tikzset{ellipsenode/.style={draw, ellipse, thick, text width=5ex, align=center, inner sep=2pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={1mm}, thick]
\node (center) [circle] {};
\node (1) at ($(center)+(240:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{1}$};
\node (2) at ($(center)+(300:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{2}$};
\node (3) at ($(center)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{3}$}; 
\node (4) at ($(center)+(60:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{4}$};
\node (5) at ($(center)+(120:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{5}$}; 
\draw[-] (1) -- (3);
\draw[-] (1) -- (2);
\draw[-] (2) -- (3);
\draw[-] (4) -- (3);
\draw[-] (5) -- (3);
\draw[-] (5) -- (4);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\hspace{30mm}
\tikzset{ellipsenode/.style={draw, ellipse, thick, text width=5ex, align=center, inner sep=2pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={1mm}, thick]
\node (center) [circle] {};
\node (1) at ($(center)+(240:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{1}$};
\node (2) at ($(center)+(300:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{2}$};
\node (3) at ($(center)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{3}$}; 
\node (4) at ($(center)+(60:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{4}$};
\node (5) at ($(center)+(120:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{5}$}; 
\draw[-] (1) -- (3);
\draw[-] (1) -- (2);
\draw[-] (2) -- (3);
\draw[-] (5) -- (3);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Individual captionss like "Figure 1 ..."  and "Figure 2..." or a shared caption with subcaptions "a) ..."  and "b)..."?

Comment: The approaches shwon in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597566/134144 should also be applicable to your graphs. Just replace the `tabular` environments with your `tkizpicture`environments.

Comment: @leandriis thank you for your reply! I think Figure 1 and Figure 2. I need to be able to add the caption also to single graphs. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that you after to have two parallel pictures with own captions. This you can simply achieved by putting pictures in `tabularx` table:

[image]

In the following MWE (Minimal Working example) is preserved their inserting in document using `center` environment and for caption are used `\captionof {figure}{<caption text>}` defined in `caption` package or you can use small `capt-of`  package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\tikzset{ellipsenode/.style = {% common style for nodes
    ellipse, draw, thick, text width=2em, align=center, inner sep=2pt},
         node distance = 21mm and 7mm
}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} C @{\hspace{30mm}} C @{}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[nodes=ellipsenode]
\node (1) {$y_{1}$};
\node (2) [above right=of 1] {$y_{3}$};
\node (3) [below right=of 2] {$y_{2}$};
\node (4) [above  left=of 2] {$y_{5}$};
\node (5) [above right=of 2] {$y_{4}$};
    \end{scope}
%
\draw   (1) -- (3) -- (2) -- (1)
        (2) -- (4) -- (5) -- (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Caption of left diagram}
\label{fig:diagram-left}
    &
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[nodes=ellipsenode]
\node (1) {$y_{1}$};
\node (2) [above right=of 1] {$y_{3}$};
\node (3) [below right=of 2] {$y_{2}$};
\node (4) [above  left=of 2] {$y_{5}$};
\node (5) [above right=of 2] {$y_{4}$};
    \end{scope}
%
\draw   (1) -- (3) -- (2) -- (1)
        (2) -- (4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Caption of right diagram}
\label{fig:diagram-right}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

However, if you like to enable to float figures to the best position in the document, you only need to replace `center` with `figure` and use standard captions commands:

```
% preamble
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\tikzset{ellipsenode/.style = {% common style for nodes
    ellipse, draw, thick, text width=2em, align=center, inner sep=2pt},
         node distance = 21mm and 7mm
}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} C @{\hspace{30mm}} C @{}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[nodes=ellipsenode]
\node (1) {$y_{1}$};
\node (2) [above right=of 1] {$y_{3}$};
\node (3) [below right=of 2] {$y_{2}$};
\node (4) [above  left=of 2] {$y_{5}$};
\node (5) [above right=of 2] {$y_{4}$};
    \end{scope}
%
\draw   (1) -- (3) -- (2) -- (1)
        (2) -- (4) -- (5) -- (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption of left diagram}
\label{fig:diagram-left}
    &
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[nodes=ellipsenode]
\node (1) {$y_{1}$};
\node (2) [above right=of 1] {$y_{3}$};
\node (3) [below right=of 2] {$y_{2}$};
\node (4) [above  left=of 2] {$y_{5}$};
\node (5) [above right=of 2] {$y_{4}$};
    \end{scope}
%
\draw   (1) -- (3) -- (2) -- (1)
        (2) -- (4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption of right diagram}
\label{fig:diagram-right}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}
```

I took a liberty to change your diagram code:

- defined are common nodes style for both pictures,
- by using `positioning` Ti*k*Z library nodes are positioned relative to each other.
- nodes are grouped by `scope`
- connections between nodes are drawn in two loops

Now the code slightly shorter.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do so is using a `\caption` in a `figure`-environment. Use it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        \centering
        \tikzset{ellipsenode/.style={draw, ellipse, thick, text width=5ex, align=center, inner sep=2pt}}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={1mm}, thick]
            \node (center) [circle] {};
            \node (1) at ($(center)+(240:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{1}$};
            \node (2) at ($(center)+(300:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{2}$};
            \node (3) at ($(center)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{3}$}; 
            \node (4) at ($(center)+(60:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{4}$};
            \node (5) at ($(center)+(120:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{5}$}; 
            \draw[-] (1) -- (3);
            \draw[-] (1) -- (2);
            \draw[-] (2) -- (3);
            \draw[-] (4) -- (3);
            \draw[-] (5) -- (3);
            \draw[-] (5) -- (4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Some cool figure}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        \centering
        \tikzset{ellipsenode/.style={draw, ellipse, thick, text width=5ex, align=center, inner sep=2pt}}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={1mm}, thick]
            \node (center) [circle] {};
            \node (1) at ($(center)+(240:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{1}$};
            \node (2) at ($(center)+(300:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{2}$};
            \node (3) at ($(center)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{3}$}; 
            \node (4) at ($(center)+(60:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{4}$};
            \node (5) at ($(center)+(120:25mm)$)[ellipsenode] {$y_{5}$}; 
            \draw[-] (1) -- (3);
            \draw[-] (1) -- (2);
            \draw[-] (2) -- (3);
            \draw[-] (5) -- (3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Another cool figure}  
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Tikz with caption]

You can also have the figures next to each: [Putting two images beside each other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148438/242407)

Has this answered your question?

Comment: @Mico Yeah, because the OP showed use without text, I thought the floating would be only more confusing. I know `H` completely disabled floating, where `ht!` doesn't, so I thought `H` would be the safe option. However, I don't have much experience with it, so I'll trust you and update my answer.